# Why does find complain of an invalid expression?

Tags: find

I have shell script like this to copy from backup file to weekly directory:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
find . type f \( -iname "SS1*.tar" -o -iname "SS2*.tar" -o -iname "SS3*.tar" -o -iname "SS4*.tar"\) -exec cp {} /backup_file/backup/weekly \;
```

So after I execute it, I get an error message: "invalid expression".

Please help me to clear this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You have two syntax error:

- `type f` must be `-type f`.
- You need a space before `\)`.

So the fixed command:

```
find . -type f \( -iname "SS1*.tar" -o -iname "SS2*.tar" -o -iname "SS3*.tar" -o -iname "SS4*.tar" \) -exec cp {} /backup_file/backup/weekly \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Simpler: `find . -type f -iname "SS[1234]*.tar" -exec cp {} /backup_file/backup/weekly \;`

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't answer the question of why Christianto's attempt didn't work.

Comment: Yes but this eliminates the problem and shows how to do it properly. Call it not an answer but workaround ;)